# Application insights alerts using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to configure application insights alerts using ARM templates. I have used the following for a server response time alert;

```
{
      "name": "[variables('responseAlertName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('components_appinsights_name'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('components_appinsights_name')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('responseAlertName')]",
        "description": "response time alert",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "condition": {
          "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('components_appinsights_name'))]",
            "metricName": "request.duration"
          },
          "threshold": "10",
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
            "sendToServiceOwners": true,
            "customEmails": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

But the issue is it's being added as a 'Classic' alert in the portal. How should the template be changed so that the alert is added as a new alert but not as a classic alert?

Comment: You can try the type ["Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2018-03-01/metricalerts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules" is the Classic metric and [Classic alerts in Azure Monitor to retire in June 2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/classic-alerting-monitoring-retirement/).

You can use the new module is [metric alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview) with the type "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts". See [Metric Alert in the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2018-03-01/metricalerts) and you will know all the properties that you can set.

For more details about the difference between Old Alert and New Alert, see [Old and New alerting capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-classic.overview#old-and-new-alerting-capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

I end up doing as following;

```
{
      "name": "[parameters('metricAlerts_web_response_time_alert_name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
      "location": "global",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "properties": {
        "description": "web server response time",
        "severity": 3,
        "enabled": true,
        "scopes": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('components_appinsights_name'))]"
        ],
        "evaluationFrequency": "Pt1m",
        "windowSize": "Pt15m",
        "criteria": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "name": "iard name",
              "metricName": "requests/duration",
              "dimensions": [],
              "operator": "GreaterThan",
              "threshold": 80,
              "timeAggregation": "Average"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "actionGroupId": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/', parameters('actionGroups_alerts_name'))]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroups_alerts_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('components_appinsights_name'))]"
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-using-migration-tool) from the Azure portal to migrate all your configured alerts to newer alerts. You may also refer to the sample template mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-a-simple-static-threshold-metric-alert) doc, or even export the template from the Azure portal to check the representation. The following template works for me:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "components_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/metricalerts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name')]",
        "location": "global",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics": "Resource",
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "[concat('Automatically created alert rule for availability test \"', parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name'), '\"')]",
            "severity": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "scopes": [
                "[parameters('webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid')]",
                "[parameters('components_test_log_analytics_externalid')]"
            ],
            "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
            "windowSize": "PT5M",
            "criteria": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.WebtestLocationAvailabilityCriteria"
            },
            "actions": []
        }
    }
]
}
```

**Note:** The retirement date for classic alerts migration has been extended to August 31st, 2019 from the originally announced date of June 30th, 2019.