# Migrating Availability Alerts from old classic to new monitorrule alerts

Tags: azure-application-insights

We had written and provisioned Availability Test Alerts in past and those show up under CLASSIC ALERTS: 
`https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AlertsBlade Following is one example of it for a WEBTEST Alert
"name": "[variables('webtest-CMS-http')]", "description": "Alert for availability test", "isEnabled": true, "condition": { "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.LocationThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client", "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.LocationThresholdRuleCondition", "dataSource": { "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client", "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource", "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/webtests', variables('webtest-CMS-http'))]", "metricName": "GSMT_AvRaW" }, "windowSize": "PT5M", "failedLocationCount": 3 }, "actions": [ { "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client", "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction", "sendToServiceOwners": false, "customEmails": "[array(parameters('webTestEmails'))]" }`

I was trying to find some documentation on how we can re-write these Alert rules with the new ALERT rules instead of classic rules. I do see an option in the portal asking for migrating the rules from classic to new but is there a JSON ARM Template way somewhere we can use? Can someone please help me with a WORKING Sample on this one? I did find this discussion here but wanted a sample for Availability Alerts:- [Application insights alerts using ARM templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361460/application-insights-alerts-using-arm-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Other than trying the [Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-using-migration-tool) from the Azure portal, you could also refer to the sample template mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-a-simple-static-threshold-metric-alert) doc, or even export the template from the Azure portal to check the representation. The following template works for me:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "components_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/metricalerts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name')]",
        "location": "global",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics": "Resource",
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "[concat('Automatically created alert rule for availability test \"', parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name'), '\"')]",
            "severity": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "scopes": [
                "[parameters('webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid')]",
                "[parameters('components_test_log_analytics_externalid')]"
            ],
            "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
            "windowSize": "PT5M",
            "criteria": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.WebtestLocationAvailabilityCriteria"
            },
            "actions": []
        }
    }
]
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Note:** The retirement date for classic alerts migration has been extended to August 31st, 2019 from the originally announced date of June 30th, 2019.